# search form redirects to home

Tags: search

**Update** 
Case closed. I forgot I have a kill function in my functions.php with redirects attachment, search, author, daily archive pages to home. Deleted the part for search and works fine.

Sorry for that, and thank you for your time and help :)

I have a simple search form in wordpress

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
  <label>
   <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="what are you looking for?" value="" name="s" title="enter search" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" class="btn search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

After I submit the form it redirects to home page. I was trying to change the action to echo `home_url( '/search.php' );` but then I get a 404.

I have got the search.php done. The code is

```
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s'), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content'); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

        <p>no results</p>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: search.php isn't accessible due to rewrite rules, you should use `get_search_form()` function, you can refer https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/.

Comment: isn't `get_search_form` only for displaying the form and not the results?

Comment: I thought you only had problem in rendering the form. You can follow https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page, and create the template.

Comment: Nope. The form is ok, I have a problem with getting the search results

Comment: you can use `get_search_query` function to retrieve all search related queries, you can pick it from any theme if you are having any trouble. You can use https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/search.php with your modifications.

Comment: Do you have search.php template in your themes directory?

Comment: If you have answered your own question, put your answer as an answer, not just an update to the question. This will help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that in my function.php I had a kill function that was redirecting to home.php my search. I just needed to delete search from the function below

```
/*  Kill attachment, search, author, daily archive pages
------------------------------------------------ */
add_action('template_redirect', 'bwp_template_redirect');
function bwp_template_redirect()
{
global $wp_query, $post;

if (is_author() || is_attachment() || is_day() || is_search() || is_multi_author() )
{
  wp_redirect(get_option('home'));
  exit;
}

if (is_feed())
{
    $author     = get_query_var('author_name');
    $attachment = get_query_var('attachment');
    $attachment = (empty($attachment)) ? get_query_var('attachment_id') : $attachment;
    $day        = get_query_var('day');
    $search     = get_query_var('s');

    if (!empty($author) || !empty($attachment) || !empty($day) || !empty($search))
    {
        $wp_query->set_404();
        $wp_query->is_feed = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to add get_search_form() function for search.php

' . get_search_query() . '' ); ?>

```
            <?php get_template_part( 'content'); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords.' ); ?></p>
        <?php
            get_search_form();

    endif;
    ?>
```